# Text editor row and font color problem ( Ubuntu 20.10 - Dark Mode active)

Tags: 20.10, text-editor

When I'm using Text Editor, the font and active row colors are the same and I can't read this text on the active row:

[image: active row with light highlighting and text in light colour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm getting same issue on Ubuntu 20.04 w/Dark Mode ... seems much better if I click in the app's hamburger menu ( the 3 horizontal bars just to right of  Save button -->
Preferences -> Font & Colors -> where I picked say  Oblivion